# Unable to initialize chrome selenium driver

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I am getting the below error while initializing the chome driver. Can anyone advise how to resolve this issue.

I am using the below versions.

- Java JDK11 (latest version)
- Selenium Jar :3.141.59 (latest version)
- Chrome 86.0.4240.183 (Official Build) (32-bit)

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

```
2020-11-04 13:12:53.293 ERROR 1656 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(boolean, java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)'
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123) ~[selenium-chrome-driver-3.141.59.jar:na]
    at au.com.optus.uam.AccountController.unlockUser(AccountController.java:47) ~[classes/:na]
```

My POM.xml is below

[image: pom 1]

[image: pom 2]

Comment: can you use \\ instead of \ in `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe");` and let me know the result?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar 
If I change, it is throwing a code compilation error as below:

 "Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )"

Comment: If this is maven project . Can you show the pom.xml . Mostly probably related to 'com.google.guava' dependency

Comment: @RahulL after adding the guava dependency, the error got resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the dependency on your pom file and try to run

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>30.0-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: after adding the above dependency, it worked beautifully. Thanks for sharing.